# Stuck on bootup screen from TWRP

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp

I am following [this guide](http://rootmygalaxy.net/flash-supersu-using-twrp-recovery-root-any-android-device/) to root my Samsung Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360T1(MetroPCS) using TWRP.

What did I wrong:

- I went into TWRP recovery
- I pressed on "Reboot"
- I pressed on "Power Off"
- A pop up came up saying "Your device is not rooted, would you like to download SuperSu now?"
- I pressed yes

Phone restarts and now is stuck on metropcs bootup screen and the interesting thing is its vibrating in a pattern... 2 vibrates then 1 after a second later and does that again in 3 seconds.

I did not put SusperSu into the internal memory so im pretty sure thats why its like "Wtf bro, where is SusperSu?"

So how do i get out of this? Help please!!!

Comment: Are you running Android Marshmallow?

Answer (score 1):

### Getting out of a bootloop

What you want to do is to **restore a working system partition**.

You have **two options available**.

### Option 1: Flashing a Custom ROM

Your first option is to [**download a custom ROM on the XDA-developers forum**.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development)
Make sure that the rom you've downloaded is for your specific model!
Mount your SDcard and copy your ROM to the device **OR** use adb and a command prompt to push the file to your SDcard

```
adb push rom.zip /sdcard
```

If you have copied the ROM onto your device, go into the Wipe section and wipe the following partitions:

- /system
- /cache
- /dalvik cache

When you are done with wiping, choose **Install** and select your custom ROM. When done flashing, reboot your device **without** confirming the root dialogue. ;)

Then you should be good to go with a working system and a pre-rooted ROM.

---

### Option 2: Installing a stock firmware.

Your second option is to flash a stock ROM (samsung).
Wipe the following partitions (should be automatically wiped when flashing with Odin but it won't hurt):

- /system
- /cache
- /dalvik cache

You can [**download the STOCK ROM from sammobile**](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-G360T1/) and follow these instructions (which can also be found on the sammobile download page)

```
Extract (unzip) the firmware file
Download Odin v3.11.1
Extract Odin ZIP file
Open Odin v3.11.1
Reboot Phone in Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
Make sure re-partition is NOT ticked
Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes
```

After this procedure your device will be stock again.

---

So which method to use? I would go for the **first option because**:

1. You will be running a **rooted** custom rom
2. You don't have to reflash a custom recovery.
3. It should be done quicker

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall SuperSu the same way but hit NO at the PopUp.
It mentions this at the bottom of the install for SuperSU, I missed it at first as well. 
One love :)

Answer (score 0):

Installing a new `ROM` just because you toasted your `supersu` installation is not a a good idea 
Before flashing a new ROM which is a lot riskier process `[unroot][1]` the `superSu` install.

```
-Download & transfer the UPDATE-unSU.zip file to your device.
-Boot your device into TWRP recovery.
-Tap the Install button on TWRP main screen » select UPDATE-unSU.zip file » and Swipe to confirm flashing the file.
-Wipe cache/dalvik from TWRP.
-Reboot phone.
```

I had this issue and did this 1st. As soon as you get lucky go back to TWRP and Backup your ROM - Stock rom 1st. **Dont attempt** anything before this . I suspect and I am almost certain the superSu failed because the bootloader was locked. 1st unlock the bootloader and then supersu ( assuming you backed up your ROM)

Answer (score -1):

Best thing is to download superuser from chainfires website and flash it with twrp instead of trying to install the super user prompt by twrp. do a factory reset in twrp. hope u dont have important data. cause sounds like to soft bricked your device